# How to play a 1GB mp4 file with html5?

Tags: html

I have a 1GB mp4 that i load with html5 plus javascript
`video.src=...
video.play();`

it plays on desktop but when i access my website on mobile, it does not. 
I am thimking that the mobile memory is too small to load the video entirely. Help me get my file to play on mobile phones and tablets.

Comment: Consider a host , and then embed the video (youtube)

Comment: It is more likely that your server configuration does not support rang based requests. But without knowing what the network tab of the remote developer tools of your mobile device shows it is not possible to tell.

Comment: @Daut not everyone wants to rely on a foreign host, does not want to include a foreign widget due to privacy policy restrictions or the licencing might also not appropriate for everyone.

Comment: @t.niece, i am using a local website for a home network.

Comment: @PaulNgom this information is as vague as it was before. As I said, it is most likely that the way how you deliver the video does not support range based requests/responses. But if this is the case and how to solve it requires first a check in the remote developer tools of your mobile device to see how the request is issued and what the response of the server is. And then it can be determined how that probably could be solved.

Comment: Does "range based requests/responses" have to do with network access? I have made shorter videos and they play. When the size gets bigger, the problems set in. The sound cannot be heard with some files and they do not play with others.

Comment: I use an iphone and i do not know how to remote debug with it.

Comment: i was able to get the mp4 file to play(with sound) on android devices by disabling firewall in my router but i cannot have sound on ios devices.